# How recursive animation works in below SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am referring an svg animation given in below link
https://codepen.io/thinkdesign/pen/JybJOq
I am not able to understand how the recursion works here

```
    var offset = 0;
var animation = function() {
  offset -= 100;
  pattern.animate({ x: offset }, 500, mina.ease, animation);
};
```

here we are changing x axis on each function call , so the x axis should go beyond screen at some point. Please help me understanding how this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is moving across the page here.  The `x` that is being moved here is the pattern's X offset.  An SVG `<pattern>` is a fill that consists of a "tile" that is repeated infinitely in every direction.  The `<pattern>` has an `x` and `y` attribute that tells the browser where to start the tiling from.  Animating the pattern's `x` offset has the effect of making it look like the tile is continuously moving across your object.

Picture a rectangular window lying on a tiled floor.  If you slide that window across the floor, it looks to you like the tile pattern moves through the window.